# Compare string using Regex for recognizing exactly the same strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a pattern like:

```
\[[0-9],([0-9]|1[0-4]),[0-9],([0-9]|1[0-4])]
```

that perfectly matches the strings that are in form of

e.g.

```
[1,1,1,2]
[5,6,5,7]
```

I want the string like

```
[1,1,1,2]kwfkbkkbdobug
```

be recognized as a false or invalid and not compatible with the pattern, while by using current pattern the string that I mentioned will be recognized as a valid string because it has a `[1,1,1,2]` string inside regardless of existence of `kwfkbkkbdobug`.

What would be the best pattern in order to satisfy the need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make use of the beginning of line anchor and the end of line anchor:

```
^\[[0-9],([0-9]|1[0-4]),[0-9],([0-9]|1[0-4])]$
```

`^` is the beginning of line anchor which matches only at the beginning of a line.

`$` is the end of line anchor which matches only at the end of a line.